# TableView running slow with many TableColumns

Tags: java-8, javafx-8

Having many rows in a TableView doesn't have as much impact on the performance as having many columns instead when using JavaFX.

I tried creating around 500 columns which creates a noticeable delay (when resizing the columns for example) but only if there's an item in the TableView which creates a row. If the TableView has no items (and thereby no rows) the performance losses are not that noticeable. Also having many rows (and just a few columns) does not create any delay (I tested this with 700 rows, having no delay at all).

So what is the reason TableView lacks performance in that specific case and is there a solution this issue?

Comment: The rows are "virtualized", meaning that cells are essentially only created for rows that are actually scrolled into view (and reused for new data as the user scrolls around). The columns are not virtualized, so cells for all columns in row will be created, configured, and added to the screen graph as soon as that row becomes visible.

Comment: OK thanks for the answer.

Comment: Facing the same problem. Did you find an answer to 'is there a solution to this issue'? It's a shame that such a central javafx widget has  performance issues. Embedding JTables in your javafx application leads to all kinds of other problems so I hope there is another solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found a solution for this by now. In my case I solved the problem by not using TableView. I know it is somehow annoying that this central JavaFX Control does have this issue. On the other hand I think that TableView was not designed to handle that many columns. It was designed to display a big amount of objects (the rows) where the columns display some kind of state (for example a column displaying an object variable).